# Overriding Porduct Grid Block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Did following steps to Override the Block file:

1) Created di.xml file in Folder `app/code/Rahul/Catalog/etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid" type="Rahul\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid" />
</config>
```

2) Created Grid.php Block file in Folder `app/code/Rahul/Catalog/Block/Rewrite/Adminhtml/Product`

```
<?php
namespace Rahul\Catalog\Block\Rewrite\Adminhtml\Product;  
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{ 
// Do your stuff here
}
?>
```

3) Cleared the cache and run upgrade command, but not worked

What things I'm missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing folder name `Rewrite` in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid" type="Rahul\Catalog\Block\Rewrite\Adminhtml\Product\Grid" />
</config>
```

Comment: thanks for correction, but after change it still not overiding

Comment: @RahulSingh i think you are trying to override the product grid? this block is not used for grid, it is using uiComponent  `product_listing`. you can override that.

Comment: Yeah, i was trying to override the grid, as i feel the grid column is coming from Grid.phtml file. can you give the full path of "uiComponent product_listing", and thanks

Comment: @RahulSingh here it is `vendor/magento/module_catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

Comment: Thanks a lot... but how to override the Ui_Component ?

Comment: @RahulSingh example for order grid but you can apply it on product grid too https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-Add-a-New-Column-to-Orders-Grid-in-Magento-2-2-2/td-p/90415

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the correct path in type in di.xml file, The path should be - `Rahul\Catalog\Block\Rewrite\Adminhtml\Product\Grid`. Please correct it and it will work.

Comment: thanks for correction, but after change it still not overriding